# Amplify js cannot authenticate a user with "responseType: code" in Next.js

Tags: next.js, amazon-cognito, amplifyjs

I'm using amplify version 5(v5.2.5) to authenticate a user in Cognito user pool with hosted UI and idp.
When I launch the Hosted UI address, redirect success to signIn URL and I have a code(example: localhost:3000/?code=abcd-xyzt-...) but the session is not stored.

Any one know the reason? Or that is an issue of Next.js?
This is my config:

```
Amplify.configure({
    Auth:
        {
            region: process.env.COGNITO_REGION,
            userPoolId: process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
            userPoolWebClientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
            mandatorySignIn: false,
            oauth: {
                domain: process.env.COGNITO_DOMAIN,
                scopes: ['email', 'openid'],
                redirectSignIn: process.env.APP_SIGN_IN_URL,
                responseType: 'code',
        },
    }
});
```

I debug with Hub and get the error: event: "signIn_failure", message: "Username and Pool information are required.". But when use responseType: 'token', it's working normally.
What's even stranger is that when I used the same configuration(same user pool, same idp, anything is the same) with two other applications using Nuxt.js and Vue.js, it worked fine with both "token" and "code" response type.

Comment: Same problem! Did you figure out the issue?